# from latitude and longitude to latitudeE6, longitudeE6

Tags: android

hi all
i have latitude and longitude points now i have to covert into latitudeE6, longitudeE6.

how to convert it. pleae guide me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert wgs 84 to lat/long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625386/convert-wgs-84-to-lat-long)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is how you should do it:

```
int latE6 = (int) (lat * 1e6);
int lonE6 = (int) (lon * 1e6);
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe on that way?

```
latE6 = (int) (lat * 1000000)
lonE6 = (int) (lon * 1000000)
```

**UPD:**

If you having your values like that x° y' z'', then:

```
valueE6 = (int) ((x + y / 60 + z / 3600) * 1000000)
```